# "windows hypervisor platform" is missing

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

I bought a new laptop with AMD ryzen 5 processor and soon I found that I'll have to enable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" to emulate android system(in Android Studio) but that option is not at all present in my windows.(Hyper-V is present but not Windows Hypervisor Platform) I've windows updated to latest version still that option is missing.
How to enable that feature or what to do to make x86 android system emulate?

Comment: Related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274510/windows-hypervisor-platform-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

- Goto `Add\Remove Programs`
- Click `Turn Windows Features on or off`
- Click `Windows Hypervisor Platform`
- Click `OK`

**SCREENSHOT:**
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The Hyper-V feature is only available on Professional editions of Windows (and other pro variant). It is not available on the Home edition.

Comment: What version/build of Windows 10 do you have?  I believe that "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is only a feature on 1803 and later.   "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is also available on Windows 10 Home.  Note that "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is not the same as the Hyper-V role, similar, but not the same.

Answer (score -2):

I just went through this on my new laptop, an HP Envy X360 with AMD Ryzen 7 2700U. In order to use the Android emulator you need to turn on "Windows Hypervisor Platform" in the list of Windows features, this feature is available in Windows 10 Home edition and will appear starting from version 1803 (April 2018 update). Turning on "Hyper-V" (found only in Windows 10 Pro) is not required. For all other requirements check this article: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html